# Breaking MongoDB $in query input array to smaller chunks improves performance?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongodb-query, aws-api-gateway

I'm running in to a performance issue on MongoDB where I'm doing an `$in` query. When the input array length of `$in` query is large (around 70) my API gateway endpoint times out since AWS API gateway endpoints times out after **30s**.

Even for smaller arrays the `$in` query takes around **21 seconds** even though it is successful which is bad

```js
    let departmentIds = [..........................  can be large]

    let query = {
      userId: someid,
      'department.department_id': {
        $in: departmentIds
      }
    };

//db query
   let result =  db
    .collection(TABLE_NAME)
    .find(query)
    .project({
      anotherfield: 1,
      department: 1
    })
    .toArray();
```

My plan was to chunk the `departmentIds` array into smaller arrays and then in a for loop do the query and concat the `result` array. My issue is will this do any improvement in performance since I'm reducing the processing from the DB side a little.

Any other strategies to improve this are welcome.

Comment: how many documents you have on your collection, 70 elements in an `$in` condition isn't too much

Comment: You have an index on `department.department_id`, yes?

Comment: @rickhg12hs ah for the moment i do not

Comment: If you create an index, it would be interesting to compare performance.

Comment: @Ayoub around 1050

Comment: @rickhg12hs if im to add an index should it be a compound index with `userId` and `department.department_id`

Comment: With only 1050 documents, I'm surprised the performance is poor.  I'm no index expert, but with so few documents, index creation will be fast - I would try many combinations of indexes and measure the performance.